# Check if textbox contains at least one phrase, then do something once

Tags: c#

I need something that checks if the textbox contains at least one phrase and repeats only once. 
Like for example, it contains "hello world"
so I write this

```
if (textbox1.Text.Contains("hello world") == true)
{  
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hi");
}
```

However, when I write hello world 2, 4, 7, etc. times in the textbox, it repeats the 'hi' statement that many times.
Is there a way i could make it so it only repeats once?

Comment: `.Contains` will give you true/false... you don't need the `== true`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve].  Your code is not a MCVE so we can't tell you why it does not behave the way you expect it to.  Also, please edit your question to add the missing info instead of adding it using comments.

Comment: A poor solution would be reserving a boolean which will turn false after first **Hi** writing, then checking that boolean _before_ your `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hi");` line. 
Like : 

    `if(haveISaidHiOnce == false){
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hi");
      haveISaidHiOnce = true;
    }`

Comment: However many times this code executes will depend on how it is run. The code you have shown us will only run the once but the event that runs it is crucial. Take a look at the page [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for an idea on how we can help you.

Comment: Are you iterating through word by word somewhere outside this scope? The iterations outside will decide how many times you will check for the string in the textbox.

Comment: Oh. So it depends on the situation? Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: @DevanshTayal If you edit your post with your specific case, we will be able to tell what's actually going on in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're running this in a loop or not, but you can do something like this:

```
bool hasPrinted = false;

if (!hasPrinted && textbox1.Text.Contains("hello world"))
{  
    hasPrinted = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hi");
}
```

This will make sure it will never fire again for the duration of the scope of `hasPrinted`.

For example, if it was in a method:

```
public void Foo()
{
    bool hasPrinted = false;

    // do stuff
}
```

It will only print once per `Foo()` call, but if it were in the class itself:

```
public class MyClass
{
    bool hasPrinted = false;

    public void Foo()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

It'll last much longer, so it's up to you were you put `hasPrinted` and where you reset it back to `false` if you want to print `hi` again.

A lot is missing in your example so it's hard to tell what your exact intent is.

Comment: Many other answers have been helpful, but this seems to work with my original code. Thank you!